# How to attach client-side event handler to a slot in a Sapper component?

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper

I'm exploring the standard svelte-sapper template and I want to add a button in the `Nav` component that will excute some login logic. I also want to separate the button's presentation and logic so I try to use slots for this. In the `Nav.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import Login from './Login.svelte';
    ...
</script>
...
        <li>
            <Login let:onclick={onclick}>
                <button onClick={onclick}>
                    Click me!
                </button>
            </Login>
        </li>
```

In the `Login.svelte`:

```
<script>
    let onclick;
    onclick = function() {
        window.alert('ALERT');
        // Browser-specific Auth0 logic goes here
    };
</script>

<div>
    <slot onclick={onclick}></slot>
</div>
```

I clearly have no idea what I'm doing because the code gets executed on server side before hydration (evidenced by a 500 error briefly shown on server route execution) and then when I click the button I get (in the browser console):

```
function() {
--------^ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
        window.alert('ALERT');
    }
```

I read about [making code execute on client only](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Making_a_component_SSR_compatible) and as much as I dislike all the boilerplate, I tried to do that and apparently slots are not passed on to child components so that to my understanding doesn't work.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to arrive at correct syntax and structure for this task.

Comment: Looks like `<button onClick={...}>` should be `<button on:click={...}>`. Regardless, it seems like there might be a bug here — are you able to rustle up a minimal repro and file an issue on https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues ?

Comment: Thanks Rich! This has sort of drifted into another issue with external dependencies for me, I'll work on it a bit more when the problem is more clear and will post to issues again